# Loading SQLite Extension in Delphi/FireDAC

Tags: sqlite, delphi

In Delphi & FireDAC & SQLite, I have successfully tried:

```
SELECT json_extract('{“a”:2,“c”:[4,5,{“f”:7}]}', '$.c[2].f'); -- works OK
```

But on the other hand, an csv example [SQLite-csv extension](https://www.sqlite.org/csv.html) didn't work:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE t1 USING csv(filename='thefile.csv'); -- Error
```

I become:
"FireDAC: ERROR: No such module: csv".
Therefore I downloaded module "csv.c" and compiled it using MSVC. Now I have the file "csv.dll" and I need to load it via

```
SELECT load_extension('csv.dll');
```

In Connection I have Extensions = True

But this attempt failed with :
"FireDAC: ERROR: No such module: csv" I also tried the absolute path to the file.

Please tell me, in general way how to load SQLite extensions in Delphi - FireDAC. Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry, the second error message should be:FireDAC: ERROR: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: 1) Can you successfully load csv.dll using a stand-alone Sqlite querying utility?  2) Have you tried calling `load_extension('csv.dll')` using FireDAC's ExecSql rather than executing a query to execute your SELECT?  3) Do you still get the error if you include the full path to csv.dll?

Comment: @MartynA. I have tried this: TSQLiteDatabase( FDConn.CliObj ).LoadExtension( 'D:\csv.dll', '' ); Without success. The same error

Comment: Ok, but what about qs 1) & 2)?

Comment: @MartynA. The error is here: sqlite> .load "D:\csv.dll"
Error: The specified module could not be found. I'm not familiar with VS. Today I downloaded & installed VS 2019. I compiled csv.c exactly as instructed here:[link](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html) "cl YourCode.c -link -dll -out:YourCode.dll".
I will probably have a problem with VS and DLL.

Comment: Shouldn't someone have SQLite extension dll sample as an example? To test where I make a mistake?